# Incompatible operand types?

Tags: android

Why would this line of code produce an error saying that `PhoneType` and `String` are incompatible operand types?

```
if(nonKeyLookupDetails.getISDCodePlusPhoneNumber() != null && nonKeyLookupDetails.getISDCodePlusPhoneNumber() != "%"
```

Comment: You will need to include slightly more of your code than just the line which produces the error.

Comment: data type returns from getISDCodePlusPhoneNumber() is not String, and you are comparing it to a String. thats why

Answer (score 0):

The "ISDCodePlusPhoneNumber" attribute will be of PhoneType and you are comparing with a string "%"(whatever you mention in quotes, java consider it as String). So when you compare with 2 different types, this error is thrown.
 nonKeyLookupDetails.getISDCodePlusPhoneNumber() != "%"

Comment: Got inside ISDCodePlusPhoneNumber class and see the attributes inside that. Then get the attribute inside that class for eg (String isdCode, Integer phoneNumber). Now you can compare the isdCode with the same comparison technique you used.